# Pork Tenderloin Safe to eat?

Tags: pork

I bought a 4 pound pork tenderloin and put it immediately in the freezer.  It was there a week or so.  Then I took it out and placed it on the counter Monday night to thaw.  I don't have central heat and my internal thermometer hasn't gotten above 40-45 in days.  I forgot about the tenderloin for about 20 hours.  I was prescribed a medication that made me rather violently ill the last two days.  When I remembered on Tuesday evening, I ran and grabbed it and threw it in the fridge.  It was cool (like it had been in the fridge) to the touch.  It was vacuum packed.  I took it out today to roast after asking for advice in a group I am in.  Everyone there said it would be fine.  I even read that the door in a fridge can get up to 59 degrees, so food stored there spoils faster.  I opened the roast and it had a slight smell.  I rinsed it and there was zero smell.  It is not slimy.  It isn't stinky.  Think it's okay to roast and eat?

Answer (score -1):

Cryopacked pork (I am assuming that's the product you have) can stink when you open the package...apparently companies have lost a lot of money due to unnecessary returns of this product. If it was cryopacked, and the package's integrity remains unquestioned, AND if the smell is *like eggs* and that's your concern, well it's supposed to be safe...I however won't buy cryopacked pork again just because I don't want to second guess myself and wonder if I am going to make myself sick...

so as you can see, this is NOT a definitive answer really...

My answer is "it's supposed to be safe, but I still don't like it"